# invalid prisma.user.create() invocation when sending a post request in postman

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, prisma

The project is with Expressjs, react, mongodb(on localhost) and prisma.When I send post request, it's throw this error:

{
"msg": "\nInvalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:\n\n{\n  data: {\n    firstName: 'sepehr',\n    ~~~~~~~~~\n    lastName: 'shirazi',\n    ~~~~~~~~\n    email: 'jfsijf@gmail.com',\n    password: '1234'\n  }\n}\n\nUnknown arg `firstName` in data.firstName for type UserCreateInput. Available args:\n\ntype UserCreateInput {\n  id?: String\n  name?: String | Null\n  email: String\n  password: String\n  posts?: PostCreateNestedManyWithoutAuthorInput\n}\nUnknown arg `lastName` in data.lastName for type UserCreateInput. Did you mean `name`? Available args:\ntype UserCreateInput {\n  id?: String\n  name?: String | Null\n  email: String\n  password: String\n  posts?: PostCreateNestedManyWithoutAuthorInput\n}\n\n"
}

What is wrong with this code?
prisma.schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id    String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  firstName String
  lastName  String
  email String? @unique
  password String
      posts Post[]

}
```

my routes:

```
import express from 'express'
import { getUser, getProductById, newUser, updateProduct, deleteProduct } from '../controller/ProductController.js'

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/users', getUser)
router.get('/products/:id', getProductById)
router.post('/users', newUser)
router.patch('/products/:id', updateProduct)
router.delete('/products/:id', deleteProduct)

export default router
```

one of my controller:

```
export const newUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body
    try {
        const user = await prisma.user.create({
            data: {
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                email: email,
                password: password
            },
        })
        res.status(201).json(user)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: error.message })
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you regenerated your Prisma schema? The one you show has `firstName` and `lastName` field, but the error suggest that the code which is running doesn't have either of those and instead has just a `name` field ("_Unknown arg `lastName` in data.lastName for type UserCreateInput. Did you mean `name`?_")

Answer (score 1):

Each time you create new model, before making post request you need to run the following command.
**npx prisma generate and npx prisma db push**

Answer (score 0):

You should run `prisma generate` and `prisma db push` after each time you modify your prisma schema